# Retaining module keys when migrating Sonar from Maven runner to Ant runner

Tags: sonarqube

We'd like to convert our existing multi-module Sonar projects that use the Maven runner to use the Ant runner instead.  These projects all use Ant for their main build anyway, and it will be a lot more convenient to have everything done with Ant.

We must preserve the history of the projects, meaning that we need to retain the keys used for the projects and their modules.  I'm having trouble doing that.

Our current Maven parent pom looks something like this (the ui is similar, though the language is Flex):

```
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>anapp</artifactId>
  <name>An Application</name>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>ui</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  </properties>   
</project>
```

The server module pom looks like this:

```
<project ...>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>anapp</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>anapp_server</artifactId>
  <name>Server</name>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <build>
    <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>build/test/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>   
  <properties>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>emma</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.emma.reportPath>build\codecoverage-results</sonar.emma.reportPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>build\test\results</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
  </properties>  
</project>
```

We set the sonar.branch property on the command line to "R7".

The key of the "myapp" project looks like

```
com.example:anapp:R7
```

The key of the "Server" module within the "myapp" project looks like this:

```
com.example:anapp_server:R7
```

For the same project to use the Ant task, I set up the properties as:

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.modules=server,ui
sonar.projectBaseDir=...
sonar.projectKey=com.example\:myapp
sonar.projectName=An Application
sonar.projectVersion=7.0

server.sonar.binaries=...
server.sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
server.sonar.emma.reportPath=...
server.sonar.java.coveragePlugin=emma
server.sonar.java.source=1.6
server.sonar.language=java
server.sonar.libraries=...
server.sonar.projectBaseDir=...
server.sonar.projectKey=com.example\:anapp_server
server.sonar.projectName=Server
server.sonar.sources=...
server.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=...
server.sonar.tests=...

ui.sonar.dynamicAnalysis=false
ui.sonar.language=flex
ui.sonar.projectBaseDir=...
ui.sonar.projectKey=com.example\:anapp_ui
ui.sonar.projectName=UI
ui.sonar.sources=...
```

The key of the project looks the same as with the pom file ("com.example:anapp:R7"); however, the server module key looks like

```
com.example:anapp:com.example:anapp_server:R7
```

This difference will cause us to lose the history of the modules if I publish using them.

Is there a way for me to specify the Ant properties to generate the same key as with our existing Maven pom files?

Our Sonar admin tells me he can manually change the keys for us, but this would be tedious and time consuming.  We'll resort to that if we have to, but I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious that would save us a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to transform Maven-style keys in standard SonarQube-style keys.

So your admin is right, the only way to do it is to manually update the keys through the interface, as [explained on the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-UpdatingProjectKey).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.